# sphinx with two arguments in group by

Tags: mysql, linux, sphinx

How I can GROUP BY in Sphinx for more than one attribute

```
    sphinx.conf

    sql_attr_uint     = brand_id
    sql_attr_uint     = resource_id
    sql_attr_uint     = is_truck
    sql_attr_uint     = kind
```

Example:

```
    SELECT 
            * 
    FROM 
            some_table
    GROUP BY 
            brand_id, resource_id
```

And sphinx tell me:

```
    SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end near ', resource_id
```

Comment: isn't the error self-explanatory?

Comment: without ", resource_id" it work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a virtual attribute. For example.

```
SELECT 
        *, (brand_id*100000)+resource_id as myint
FROM 
        some_table
GROUP BY 
        myint
```

Just make 100000 be bigger than your highest resource_id